# Firebase ML-Kit run multiple face detection sessions in parallel

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, parallel-processing, kotlin-coroutines

As part of my ML project, I want to generate training data for analyzing the face of multiple individuals from different images using the face detector  [Google Firebase ML-Kit Face detection library](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/detect-faces). I created a very simple service class to encapsulate the initialization and start the process of face detection:

```
class FaceDetectorService(private val act: MainActivity)  {

private var opts: FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions? = null
private var detector: FirebaseVisionFaceDetector? = null


init {
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(act)

    opts = FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
        .setPerformanceMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ACCURATE)
        .setLandmarkMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.NO_LANDMARKS)
        .setClassificationMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.NO_CLASSIFICATIONS)
        .setContourMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_CONTOURS)
        .build()

    detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
        .getVisionFaceDetector(opts!!)
}


suspend fun analyzeAsync(cont: Context, uri: Uri) : Pair<String, Task<List<FirebaseVisionFace>>> {
    val image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFilePath(cont, uri)

    // this is for the UI thread
    withContext(Main){
        act.addItemToAnalyze(uri.lastPathSegment)
    }

    // return the filename too
    return Pair(uri.lastPathSegment, detector!!.detectInImage(image))
}
```

}

The function *detector!!.detectInImage* ([FirebaseVisionImage.detectInImage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/vision/face/FirebaseVisionFaceDetector#detectInImage(com.google.firebase.ml.vision.common.FirebaseVisionImage)) ) returns a [Task](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/tasks/Task) that represents async operations.

In the onResume() function of my MainActivity, inside a CoroutineScope, I fire up the lib and start iterating over the images converting them to an Uri first then passing it to the face detector:

```
CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
        val executeTime = measureTimeMillis {
            for (uri in uris){

                    val fileNameUnderAnalysis = uri.lastPathSegment
                    //val tsk = withContext(IO) {
                    //    detector!!.analyzeAsync(act, uri)
                    //}
                val tsk = detector!!.analyzeAsync(act, uri)
                tsk.second.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful && task.result!!.isNotEmpty()) {
                        try {
                           // my best
                        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
                           // fire
                        }
                    } else if (task.result!!.isEmpty()) {
                       // not today :(
                    }

                }

                tsk.second.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                    // on error
                }
            }

        }
        Log.i("MILLIS", executeTime.toString())
    }
```

Now, although my implementation runs concurrently (that is, *starting* at the same time), what I actually want is to run them in parallel (*running* in the same time depending on the number of threads, which is 4 in my case on an emulator), so my goal would be to take the number of available threads and assign an analysis operation to each of them quartering the execution time.

What I tried so far is, inside the *CoroutineScope(IO).launch* block,  encapsulating the call to the library in a task:

```
val tsk = async {
    detector!!.analyzeAsync(act, uri)
}

val result = tsk.await()
```

and a job:

```
val tsk = withContext(IO) {
   detector!!.analyzeAsync(act, uri)
}
```

but the async operations I manually start always last only as long as the Firebase tasks are started, not waiting for the inner task to run to completion. I also tried adding different *withcontext(...)* and *...launch {}* variations inside the class *FaceDetectorService*, but to no avail.

I'm obviously very new to kotlin coroutines, so I think I'm missing something very basic here, but I just cannot wrap my head around it.

(PS: please do not comment on the sloppiness of the code, this is just a prototype :) )

Comment: There's a lot of work here... The current `analyzeAsync` is a `suspend fun` and also returns async `Task`. It shouldn't switch contexts and it shouldn't update the GUI. It should focus on the ML work and return the result of `Task.await()`, this removes the need for `addOnCompleteListener`. Update the GUI in another function that you don't call from `analyzeAsync`. The overall work shouldn't start in the `IO` dispatcher but `Main`. Once you straighten out the scoping of work that is currently async, the awaiting problem should either go away or become easy to resolve.

Comment: CPU-intensive work should be on `Default` instead of `IO`, but since it's behind a `Task`, i don't think you have any control on thread choice for it. So probably all you need is the `Main` dispatcher because all you do on your threads is await.

Comment: I couldn't find explicit details on it, but it is highly likely that a single face detection call already uses all the available CPU, so parallelizing either isn't possible or won't bring any speedup.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! You are of course right in pointing out that a context-switch to the ui thread does not belong in a service, this was only becuase of prototyping reasons :). The remark on the CoroutineScope is duly noted.

The android Task api has no await functionality built in, sadly, only callbacks can be used to asynchornously obtain the result. That being said, I agree with you on  having a separate Firebase Task means I have no control over the execution.

If you could convert these 3 comments into an answer, I'm happy to accept it :)

Comment: As an extra, it turns out that the Firebase ML-Kit vision api uses bitmaps heavily storing reference to the images under computation even if the task itself is only scheduled to be executed later. This of course means that if one wants to analyze multiple images, the ram consumption will skyrocket with no real use easily leading to app crashes even on 3-4 GBs of ram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`analyzeAsync()` is a `suspend fun` and also returns a future-like `Task` object. Instead it should return the result of `Task.await()`, which you can easily implement basically by factoring out your `addOnCompleteListener` call:

```
suspend fun <T> Task<T>.await(): T = suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
    addOnCompleteListener {
        val e = exception
        when {
            e != null -> cont.resumeWithException(e)
            isCanceled -> cont.cancel()
            else -> cont.resume(result)
        }
    }
}
```

An optimzied version is available in the [`kotlinx-coroutines-play-services`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services) module).

Since the face detection API is already async, it means the thread you call it on is irrelevant and it handles its computation resources internally. Therefore you don't need to launch in the `IO` dispatcher, you can use `Main` and freely do GUI work at any point, with no context switches.

As for your main point: I couldn't find explicit details on it, but it is highly likely that a single face detection call already uses all the available CPU or even dedicated ML circuits that are now appearing in smartphones, which mean there's nothing to parallelize from the outside. Just a single face detection request is already getting all the resources working on it.